# Are questions confirming 100% completion possibility on topic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, questions

Before sinking the time into properly developing such a question, I wanted to confirm if questions asking about the possibility of 100% completing a game is on-topic for this site. With complex games with branching pathways it can be hard to find out:

1. When it is possible to complete everything in one playthrough, and
2. What special considerations or ordering of events need to be done to complete everything in a game.
    <sub>*Note when I say complete everything, I am being intentionally vague, as that will vary from game to game. For any question about a specific game it would need to specify which specific metrics are being included in completing everything so as not to be open-ended.*</sub>

I tried looking for questions along these lines on the site and found some related to completing specific items (for example making every recipe, learning every spell, etc.), but couldn't seem to find any specifically about fully completing a game and what that entails for a specific game. So I ask here,

*Are these types of question on-topic?*
*If so any watch-outs when formulating such a question?*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would say they are on topic, but things that would bluntly be 'what would be the checklist for 100%' would be not very well received. Mostly, I think, it's because usually the game is pretty obvious as to what is considered completion; and if it doesn't, usually 100% completion becomes where you put the bar yourself.

And for the 2 you are asking, I think they would be decently received. Makes me think of a question I've asked in the past: [Are there any missable sidequests?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/302511/are-there-any-missable-sidequests)

Other questions related to completion that would be well received is an explainer of what does the % complete indicator contains, like these: [How does Genshin Impact judge area completion percentage?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/390690/how-does-genshin-impact-judge-area-completion-percentage) and [Is there any way to view the completion percentage of the game?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/302537/is-there-any-way-to-view-the-completion-percentage-of-the-game)

But at the end of the day, the simplest thing is to try and see. Don't be scared by the downvotes, we don't put people in jail if their question goes into the negatives.

Comment: "we don't put people in jail if their question goes into the negatives" -- I mean, _technically_ if you make a habit of this you'll get a question ban ... which could be considered "jail".